# 'At the seaside' vs 'on the beach'

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference, word-difference

I wonder if there are any differences between two sentences below:

> I was at the seaside last summer.
>
> I was on the beach last summer.

Are they have the same meaning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say they are pretty close, but a seaside resort might encompass more than a beach. So, you might have taken a seaside vacation, and never felt the beach sand between your toes. Instead, you might have participated in activities such as golf:

[image: Links golf course above cliffs]

Your second sentence, therefore, is more specific, and makes it clear that you weren’t merely at the seaside, but on the beach:

[image: Sandy beach]

Comment: “To be on the beach” - may be a phrase meaning to be out of job (as a sailor on the shore that is out of job). Real meaning here is context dependent. Had one having a vacation or lost job?